# Share a link without "...shared a link"

Tags: facebook, sharing

When PCMag share a link, it says "PCMag"

When I share a link to my webpage is says " 'Name of my page' shared a link"

How do I share a link without it saying, "shared a link".

Comment: You just need to include a message in your post, e.g. "This was an amazing year for tech geeks.". Notice that all of PCMag's posts have a message.

Comment: Oh, that simple huh. Thanks